# Get quote by reserved order id

Tags: magento

I want to create a new payment method. On checkout process payment method redirects to 3-rd party service. I pass reservedOrderId to 3-rd party service and it returns this id back on payment success. How can I get quote by reservedOrderId? Or need I convert quote to order before redirecting to 3-rd party service?

Comment: this is not enough information to help you. show us your code, what 3rd party service you are using, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the reserved order should be unique, you can try this:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('reserved_order_id', 'Your Order id')
    ->getFirstItem();

if ($quote->getId()) {
   //quote was found - $quote
}
else {
   //the quote does not exist.
}
```

Comment: `Mage::getSingleton('sales/quote')->load($orderId, 'reserved_order_id')` works

Comment: edit: `reserver_order_id` must be `reserved_order_id`

Comment: @nicolallias. Thanks for spotting this.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine:

*Note that `$orderId` is order `increment_id` column value, not id for the row in the database*

```
Mage::getSingleton('sales/quote')
     ->load($orderId, 'reserved_order_id')
```

Thanks to @Sergei

Answer (score 1):

In Magento2 you can load a quote by reserved order id in the following way:

```php
namespace Tschallacka\TestPlugin\Quote;

use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote as QuoteResource;

class Test 
{
    const RESERVED_ORDER_FIELD = 'reserved_order_id';

    protected $quoteFactory;
    protected $quoteResource;

    public function __construct(
        QuoteFactory $quoteFactory, 
        QuoteResource $quoteResource
    ) {
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
        $this->quoteResource = $quoteResource;
    }
 
    /** @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote **/
    public function loadQuote() 
    {
       $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create();
       $this->quoteResource->load($quote, 'test_quote', self::RESERVED_ORDER_FIELD);
       return $quote;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better convert quote to order before you send to third part. it will permit you to have the correct status for the order (cancelled, paid, fraud....).

If you really need to create the order after, you can override mage_sales_model_quote and mage_sales_model_resource_quote to create the according function loadByReservedOrderId() the resource one with the call to database and the model to permit you to call it on a controller.

for resource, something like that would do.

```
public function loadByReservedOrderId($id){
    $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()->from(array('main_table'=>$this->getMainTable()), 'entity_id')
        ->where('main_table.reserved_order_id = ?', array($id));

    return $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchOne($select);
}
```

for the model :

```
public function loadByReservedOrderId($id)
{
    if ($id == null){
        return  false;
    }
    $order_id = $this->_getResource()->loadByReservedOrderId($id);
    $this->load($order_id);
    return $this;
}
```